# Find Longest Word Not Working

Tags: python, string, list

So I was exploring on coderbyte.com and one of the challenges is to find the longest word in a string. My code to do so is the following:

```
def LongestWord(sen): 

  current="";
  currentBest=0
  numberOfLettersInWord=0
  longestWord=0
  temp=sen.split()

  for item in temp:

    listOfCharacters=list(item)

    for currentChar in listOfCharacters:

      if currentChar.isalpha():

        numberOfLettersInWord+=1

    if numberOfLettersInWord>longestWord:

      longestWord=numberOfLettersInWord

      numberOfLettersInWord=0

      currentBest=item

  z = list(currentBest)

  x=''

  for item in z:

    if item.isalpha(): x+=item


  return x

testCase="a confusing /:sentence:/ this"  
print LongestWord(testCase)
```

when testCase is "a confusing /:sentence:/"

The code returns confusing, which is the correct answer. But when the test case is the one in the current code, my code is returning 'this' instead of 'confusing'

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You loop through the words composing the sentence. However, `numberOfLettersInWord` is never reseted so it keeps increasing while you iterate among the words.

You have to set the counter to `0` each time you start a new word.

```
for item in temp:
    numberOfLettersInWord = 0
```

It solves your issue as you can see: https://ideone.com/y1cmHX

Comment: Oh I see, I only reset if it is the new longest word, otherwise it keeps adding up and eventually the length is greater than the length of the actual longest word. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another approach, which is more modular and more Pythonic.

Let's make a function to measure word length:

```
def word_length(w):
    return sum(ch.isalpha() for ch in w)
```

So it will count (using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)) how many characters there are for which `.isalpha()` is `True`:

> >>> `word_length('hello!!!')`
>
> 5
>
> >>> `word_length('/:sentence:/')`
>
> 8

Now, from a list of words, create a list of lengths. This is easily done with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

> >>> `sen = 'a confusing /:sentence:/ this'.split()`
>
> >>> `map(word_length, sen)`
>
> [1, 9, 8, 4]

Another builtin useful to find the maximum value in a list is [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

> >>> `max(map(word_length, sen))`
>
> 9

But you want to know the word which maximizes the length, which in mathematical terms is called [argument of the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

To solve this, [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lengths with the words, and get the second argument found by [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max).

Since this is useful in many cases, make it a function:

```
def arg_max(func, values):
    return max(zip(map(func, values), values))[1]
```

Now the longest word is easily found with:

> >>> `arg_max(word_length, sen)`
>
> 'confusing'

---

Note: [PEP-0008 (Style Guide for Python Code)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) suggests that function names be lower case and with words separated by underscore.

Comment: Although it is way shorter than mine and probably runs a lot faster, it is really hard to read and some parts are confusing and it doesn't answer my original question. Thanks for the answer though, I will look more into how lambda works.

Comment: The point is that you can do lot with a single line using 4 Python builtins, rather than writing 20 lines of *C-style* Python code ;-)

Comment: Yeah but if you're working with other people on a program or asked to do so in an interview question, they might find your way unappealing.

Comment: If in my team I have to code at the skill level of the least skilled developers, I'd certainly fire those developers.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the answer to your question, but this is how I would calculate the longest word. And not sharing it, wouldn't help you, either:

```
import re


def func(text: str) -> str:
    words = re.findall(r"[\w]+", text)
    return max(words, key=len)

print(func('a confusing /:sentence:/ this'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a little function I just wrote that will return the longest word, using a regular expression to remove non alpha-numeric characters

```
import re

def longest_word(input):
    words = input.split()
    longest = ''
    for word in words:
        word = re.sub(r'\W+', '', word)
        if len(word) > len(longest):
            longest = word
    return longest

print(longest_word("a confusing /:sentence:/ this"))
```

Comment: The point is to solve his issue so he can learns from his mstake.

Comment: Sorry - I just realised I wasn't actually answering your question, this is just another way of doing it.

Comment: @Delgan - yes. I realised as soon as I posted it.